# JavaScript copyToClipboard on iPhone iOS without prompt window

Tags: javascript, iphone, clipboard

I use the following JS in order to copy text to clipboard on button click:

```
window.copyToClipboard = (string) => {
  let textarea;
  let result;

  try {
    textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
    textarea.setAttribute('readonly', true);
    textarea.setAttribute('contenteditable', true);
    textarea.style.position = 'fixed'; // prevent scroll from jumping to the bottom when focus is set.
    textarea.value = string;

    document.body.appendChild(textarea);

    textarea.focus();
    textarea.select();

    const range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(textarea);

    const sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);

    textarea.setSelectionRange(0, textarea.value.length);
    result = document.execCommand('copy');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    result = null;
  } finally {
    document.body.removeChild(textarea);
  }

  // manual copy fallback using prompt
  if (!result) {
    const isMac = navigator.platform.toUpperCase().indexOf('MAC') >= 0;
    const copyHotkey = isMac ? '⌘C' : 'CTRL+C';
    result = prompt(`Press ${copyHotkey}`, string); // eslint-disable-line no-alert
    if (!result) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

I found this JS somewhere else on google or SO.
Everything works fine, except on my iPhone it shows some prompt window with text and asks user to press CTRL+C. Is there a better version of such JS in order to copy text without any prompt window on iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [native API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/writeText) - `navigator.clipboard.writeText()`